# Migrate "Manager" from Flask-Script to Flask CLI

Tags: python, flask

I'm not quite sure how to migrate this simple old Flask-Script **manage.py** to the CLI provided in Flask 0.11+

```
from flask_script import Manager
from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand

from app import app, db

migrate = Migrate(app, db)
manager = Manager(app)

manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    manager.run()
```

It is used like this, with Flask Migrate:

```
python manage.py db migrate
```

Following the [Flask 2.x documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/cli/#custom-commands) I can get as far as:

```
import click
from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand

from app import app, db

@app.cli.command("db")
@click.argument("migration_command")
def handle_command(migration_command):
    print("Handling command {}".format(migration_command))
```

But when running:

```
python manage.py db migrate
```

But it appears `handle_command` is never called, and the `db migrate` command does not seem to run.

Also, what is the Flask CLI equivalent for:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    manager.run()
```

Since `manager` is no longer available? If I replace it with `app.run()`, it appears to ignore all the CLI parameters and the `handle_command` is never called.

Also, how about `MigrateCommand` in this:

```
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)
```

I presume is creates an enumeration of available commands for `db`? Where do I pass `MigrateCommand` when using Flask CLI? The [documentation for Flask Migrate](https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#using-flask-script) is not really clear is it required or not when using Flask CLI.

Answer (score 1):

I am still trying to get it working, but I can answer some of your queries:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    manager.run()
```

Here, manager.run() becomes cli()

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli()
```

In commands like these:

```
python manage.py db migrate
```

replace python manage.py with flask everywhere, such as 'flask db migrate', etc.

```
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)
```

Here, replace manager by cli. So, the above command becomes cli.add_command(...)